# Android canvas: lines and ovals scale, but paths don't?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using a square shaped canvas in my application and my goal is to draw everything between 0.0/0.0 (top left corner) and 1.0/1.0 (bottom right corner) so that I can scale it up later on, depending on the screen size.

This works fine for some of the basic drawing methods, but not for paths. My onDraw-method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(getWidth(), getWidth());
    canvas.drawOval(outerRect, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0.5f, 0.05f, 0.5f, 0.95f, linePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, linePaint);
}
```

Definitions of outerRect and trianglePath:

```
outerRect = new RectF(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.95f, 0.95f);

trianglePath = new Path();
trianglePath.moveTo(0.05f, 0.05f); 
trianglePath.lineTo(0.95f, 0.05f);
trianglePath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.95f);
trianglePath.close();
```

As you can see, there's no triangle in the result:

[image]

Why is that?

**edit: the whole view**

```
public class PlaygroundView extends View {

    private Paint linePaint;
    private RectF outerRect;
    private Path trianglePath;

    private final int preferredSize = 300;

    public PlaygroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        outerRect = new RectF(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.95f, 0.95f);

        trianglePath = new Path();
        trianglePath.reset();
        trianglePath.moveTo(0.05f, 0.05f); 
        trianglePath.lineTo(0.95f, 0.05f);
        trianglePath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.95f);
        trianglePath.close();

        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.01f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

        int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
    }

    private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
        if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            return size;
        } else { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            return preferredSize;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(getWidth(), getWidth());
        canvas.drawOval(outerRect, linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0.5f, 0.05f, 0.5f, 0.95f, linePaint);
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, linePaint);
    }
}
```

**edit #2:**

Well, this is strange. A newly created emulator instance shows the circle and the line, but not the triangle, whereas the IDE preview shows the triangle, but not the circle and the line. Both based on the same code which I rebuilt several times...

[image]

Comment: it should work,  make sure that your Path is not empty in onDraw

Comment: @pskink maybe you could take a look at the edit, I posted the whole class

Comment: i run it and there is a triangle on top of the view... but quality is very very bad...

Comment: @pskink as you can see above, things are getting weird. I'm giving up for today, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: most likely issue of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @cera were you able to find a solution to scale the canvas without losing the path quality?